# How do I transpose a Future out of an Option?

Tags: rust, async-await, option-type, rust-futures

Is there a more idiomatic or prettier way to do an operation like this in rust?

```rust
let maybe_output = match maybe_input {
    Some(input) => Some(async_result(input).await?),
    None => None,
};
```

I tried to use `map` like this,

```rust
let maybe_output = maybe_input.map(|input| async_result(input).await?);
```

but I cannot use the `.await` and `?` operators inside a lambda that doesn't return a future or a result.  I suspect I can do the map and have an `Option<Future<Result<_>>>`, then sequence out the `Future<Result<_>>` to be `Future<Result<Option<_>>>`;

```
let maybe_output = maybe_input.map(|input|
    async_result(input)
).transpose().await?;
```

but I don't know if I can call `transpose` on a Future since it's a trait not a type like Result or Option.

Comment: It would be nice if `Option<T: Future>` implemented `Future`, I found a relevant discussion [here](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/impl-t-future-future-for-option-t/14165) but it doesn't appear it went anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [`OptionFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/future/struct.OptionFuture.html) in the `futures` crate:

```
let maybe_output = OptionFuture::from(maybe_input.map(async_result)).await;
```

However, I would personally consider the original form more idiomatic. I can immediately understand what the `match` does, while I'd have to take a second look to know that `OptionFuture` does what I'd expect.

Comment: strange to not have a trait `ToFutureOption` well `into()` work well too